# How to include buttons in Civimail

Tags: civimail, custom-templates

I want to include two buttons in civimail template Accept and Decline. If the user clicks on accept/ decline button, It should notify the administrator with an email.However I can add buttons using HTML.But how do I make this to notify the administrator with an email?Please suggest.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about link your two buttons to two different URLs (confirmation pages) "Thank you for voting yes"; "Thank you for voting no" and use the CiviMail track open/click through feature to see which Contacts clicked which buttons.

Answer (score 1):

Create "Accept" and "Decline" landing pages and link your template to them. Use the Mailing Report to track who has accepted or declined.

---